# Python PANDAS: Error in reading the first few lines of a CSV Files which doesn't have a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, scripting

I have a `.csv` file generated by a sensor module. I am trying to separate the values, with comma as my delimiter. ***The generated CSV files contains three lines in the beginning which don't have any delimiter. Those lines just indicate the name of the sensor and the manufacturer name. But the real delimited values start from the fourth line.***

When I pass the file to the script, it is throwing an error `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 3`

But, when I manually delete the first 3 lines present in the file and then pass the edited file to my script, the automation is perfect. But when I pass the unedited file to my script, it is failing to even open it.

`fileName = 'sensormodule.csv'`

`df = pd.read_csv(fileName)`

Would be great if you could provide me suggestions.

Comment: try `skiprows` i.e `df = pd.read_csv(fileName,skiprows=3)`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot.